# Graph deep clone with SQL or javascript function

Tags: orientdb

Is there a SQL way to achieve OrientDB deep cloning?

Or otherwise is there a javascript server function (in orientdb studio) approach that can achieve it?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible natively.

Comment: I thought that with SQL was not possible but that the server side javascript could do it with some code.

Comment: What about first export and then import the database?

Comment: It's not for my use case, I'd like to clone part of the tree for application related tasks.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with this little graph

[image]

[image]

and I used this server side javascript function

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var myedge=g.command("sql","select @class as myclass,out,in from e");
for(i=0;i<myedge.length;i++){
    var myEdgeClass=myedge[i].getProperty("myclass");
    var VertexOutId= myedge[i].getProperty("out").getId();
    var VertexInId= myedge[i].getProperty("in").getId();

    var VertexOut=g.command("sql","select @class as myclass,@this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 out_*:-2') as json          from " + VertexOutId);                                       
    var query="insert into " + VertexOut[0].getProperty("myclass") + " content"+VertexOut[0].getProperty("json");
    var copyVertexOut=g.command("sql",query);
    g.commit();

    var VertexIn=g.command("sql","select @class as myclass,@this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 out_*:-2') as json           from " + VertexInId);                                       
    query="insert into " + VertexIn[0].getProperty("myclass") + " content"+VertexIn[0].getProperty("json");
    var copyVertexIn=g.command("sql",query);
    g.commit();

    query="create edge " + myEdgeClass + " from " + copyVertexOut.getId() + " to " + copyVertexIn.getId(); 
    g.command("sql",query);

}
```

and I got

[image]

[image]

I hope it could be a help and a starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro it is indeed a great starting point! Even if I wonder if there are specific Java functions calls from javascript.